# as3 - How do you stop moving when touching an object?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I make the player stop when it's collding with an object but when it's touching the x side of an object, it can still slide up and down, and when it's touching the y side of an object, it can still slide side to side while colliding.

Here is my code for player movement.

```
public function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            isRight = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            isLeft = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            isUp = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            isDown = true;
        }
    }

public function onEnterFrame(event: Event): void
    {
        if (isRight)
        {
            x += 5;
        }
        if (isLeft)
        {
            x -= 5;
        }
        if (isUp)
        {
            y -= 5;
        }
        if (isDown)
        {
            y += 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried [`obj.hitTestPoint()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()) or [`obj.hitTestObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()) ... ?

Answer (score 0):

On each tick of movement (OnEnterFrame in your case) you should perform the following basic steps:

1. Save player's x and y into variables
2. Calculate new position
3. Check if player overlaps any objects or level boundaries in his new position. This can be done in a variety of ways; it's not possible to elaborate without knowing the structure of your level, shape of player, shapes of obstacles, how you store the information about them.
4. For every overlapping object calculate **how much** the player overlaps the object and solve the collision by moving player back in its track so that he doesn't collide. You have the previous and the next coordinates, so, you have a vector along which to move the player back.

The difficulty of these steps depends greatly on shapes of objects in question, on maximum relative velocity of colliding objects, on required accuracy of collision solving. If you are dealing with primitives like rectangles and circles that can be relatively easy to implement, albeit there still will be difficult cases like collisions with several objects. Here are some basic tools you may want to look at:

- [getBounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29)
- [hitTestPoint](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29)
- [hitTestObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29)
- [Rectangle.intersects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#intersects%28%29)

Detecting and solving collisions is one of the most common problems in game development, so you may easily find tons of material on the subject on the net. For instance:

- [N Tutorial A - Collision Detection and Response](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)
- [N Tutorial B - Broad-Phase Collision](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialB.html)